# Proper way to preserve data for mariadb docker container

Tags: mariadb, docker

I am running a single mariadb container as a backend for a webapp. I restarted the container, and the only data remaining was from a long time ago. None of the recent transactions were available. They are seemingly all gone.

I thought that I had prevented this from happening by using volumes for the database files, but after talking to one of my DBA colleagues, I went back and checked, and sure enough, the last modification date for those files was far in the past.

My question is that if shutting down a mariadb docker container wipes all of the transactions from memory without writing them to disk, how am I supposed to preserve data during a database restart?

FWIW, I am using the official mariadb docker container image, which kills the process with a SIGTERM, and my data volume is linked to `/var/lib/mysql`, which is where I understood all of the data to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

Is this still relevant?

You haven't mentioned what your host is (I take it it is Windows). From what you mentioned, I assume also, you used mapping to host system (full path) and not. named (docker managed) volumes. 
In addition it would be important to know -- if your host is indeed windows -- how you installed docker (docker desktop in hyper-v, virualbox/vmware)

I go by what I got and guess to start:

The constallation Docker on Windows and host volumes -- especially for databases -- is known to cause problems (see e.g. 
https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/issues/152 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343972/docker-volumes-mariadb-windows)

If my guesses are right, then two things strike me as strange though:
1. How could this mariadb docker ever have worked and 
2. where do those old database-files come from? 
Is it possible these are an old artefact from a different (possibly local) installation?

You imply that possibly shutting down the mariadb container some time in the past (SIGTERM) lost the connection to the volume and on restart continued to work but that does not seem to match up with other evidence you provide (it obviously did work well up until your last (first?) restart of the container).

Could something have changed with the access-rights to the files or the folder on the host (although that would speak more for a Linux host)? See https://medium.com/@nielssj/docker-volumes-and-file-system-permissions-772c1aee23ca for further information. Again, this does not explani why  mariadb did still run up until the problem you noticed.

Closing (again assuming this is Docker on Windows) your problem might be much smaller now (speaking after Windows 10 2004 was released) using Docker in WSL 2 because you can use named (docker managed) volumes and still easily access these as linux folders in wsl 2 are directly mounted in Windows.

Sorry, this is probably not the answer you expected. If you clarify your situation I (or somebody else) might be able to be more specific.